# How to optimize this loop that purges duplicate vertices?

Tags: c#, performance, optimization

I have this bit of code here

```
var vertexIndexDictionary = new Dictionary<Vector3, int>();
for (int i = 0; i < triangles.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        var vertex = triangles[i][j];
        if (!vertexIndexDictionary.ContainsKey(vertex))
        {
            vertexIndexDictionary.Add(vertex, vertexIndexDictionary.Count);
        }
    }
}
var vertices = vertexIndexDictionary.Keys.ToArray();
```

which goes through the `triangles` array and gets rid of duplicate vertices. This triangle array can get very large, and so the running time gets really long as well. Is there some way I can achieve the same thing but faster? E.g. with another data type?

Edit:
Triangles array is initialized like this:

```cs
var triangles = new Triangle[count];
```

and triangle struct is

```cs
struct Triangle {
    public Vector3 a;
    public Vector3 b;
    public Vector3 c;

    public Vector3 this[int i]
    {
        get
        {
            switch (i)
            {
                case 0:
                    return a;
                case 1:
                    return b;
                default:
                    return c;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You do realize that even if there would be an in-built method for this functionality it would eventually need to loop the array? there isn’t really a black magic available to access the content of an array. so IMHO you found a solution to your problem than great, don’t try to hard to make it the smartest Code human possible, it works than it’s fine, try to fix things that are actually broken

Comment: Could you include in the question the definition of the `triangles` array? Also your code doesn't only initialize the `vertices` array. It initializes also the `indices` array. What is the meaning of this array? What is represented by its values?

Comment: @RandRandom It is broken though as it takes way too long to execute. What I am asking is if there is maybe another data type that might achieve the same thing more efficiently. E.g. I know for certain situations a sorted array is faster to process (even though I do not know if a sorted array can apply here) or using binary trees for certain tasks is faster than using some other data type.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Updated my post to include the definitions. The indices array references the vertices in the vertices array. E.g. the vertex array might contain `(vertex1, vertex2, vertex3, vertex4)` and the indices array might contain `(0,1,2,0,2,3)` which means the program will join vertex1, vertex2 and vertex3 to form a triangle, vertex1, vertex 3 and vertex4 to form another triangle.

Comment: You could rewrite your code as `var vertices = triangles.SelectMany(t => Enumerable.Range(0, 3).Select(i => t[i])).Distinct().ToArray();` but I don't think it'll be any faster. You must iterate over your vertices to do what you are asking. There's no other choice.

Comment: @ItsPiscerii - How are you building `triangles` in the first place? Can we see that code?

Comment: @Enigmativity I am implementing the Marching cubes algorithm in a compute shader. Each cube is calculated in parallel. I build triangle structs in the shader based on the triangulation table, then I append the struct to a buffer so that the 3 vertices in the same triangle will not be separated from other vertices that were appended on from another thread. This also means that triangles that are in the same cube will not always be next to one another. Should I update my post to include the compute shader as well?

Comment: If you can make your Vertex class implement the  [IEquatable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-collections-generic-dictionary-2-ctor(system-collections-generic-iequalitycomparer((-0))))interface, you can then load them into a HashSet. HashSets are inherently deduplicated.

Comment: @O.Jones - Which is how `.Distinct()` works. LINQ is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You could get direct access to the entry stored inside the `vertexIndexDictionary`, with the low-level [`CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrAddDefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.collectionsmarshal.getvaluereforadddefault) method. Using this API you can reduce the dictionary searching operations from 2-3 to just 1 per iteration. Also you could consider avoiding using the LINQ [`ToArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.toarray) method, because LINQ in general is not the tool of choice when performance is of uttermost importance. In this particular case avoiding the `ToArray` is unlikely to provide any tangible benefit (because the LINQ happens to be internally optimized for sources that implement the `ICollection<T>` interface), but I'll show you how to do it anyway:

```
for (int i = 0; i < triangles.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        Vector3 vertex = triangles[i][j];
        ref int valueRef = ref CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrAddDefault(
            vertexIndexDictionary, vertex, out bool exists);
        if (!exists) valueRef = vertexIndexDictionary.Count;
        indices[i * 3 + j] = valueRef;
    }
}
Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[vertexIndexDictionary.Keys.Count];
vertexIndexDictionary.Keys.CopyTo(vertices, 0);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, because I am using Unity and it has not updated to .NET 5 yet, the collectionsmarshal class isn't available yet. I am currently searching for a workaround (maybe by importing the new dll myself?) but I don't think that would work.

Comment: @ItsPiscerii hmm, I don't think that it's possible to backport this .NET 6 type to an earlier .NET version, other than taking the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/Dictionary.cs) of the `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` and trying to make it compile on your target .NET version. Which should be extremely painful and laborious, because it depends on other internal types.